# Vlookup Range as the Lookup_Value

Tags: excel, vlookup

I have a file that does a series of vlookups in cells C2 through C21. I noticed someone using the Vlookup where the lookup value is a range. So instead of doing

```
=VLOOKUP($B2,$E$2:$F$7,2,FALSE)
```

They are doing the vlookup as such:

```
=VLOOKUP($B$2:$B$21,$E$2:$F$7,2,FALSE)
```

Is there any benefit to doing it this way?

Comment: The only benefit I can see is that you could use it as an array formula ans wrap it in a sum, or other aggregation formula.

Comment: How would you go about doing that. I tried 
={SUM(VLOOKUP($B$2:$B$21,$E$2:$F$7,2,FALSE))} 
and all it does is return the vlookup using cell B2.

Comment: Strange, it actually doesn't work for that. It seems like it should.